# Does stopping tomcat stops Spring scheduler/crons jobs on linux?

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, cron-task, spring-scheduled

I have a requirement wherein I am creating few spring schedulers to delete some DB records. 
When the spring application stops, do these schedulers stop automatically? 
On Linux, will these jobs be running as cron jobs? 
If yes, by stopping tomcat on which app is running, do these jobs get terminated?

Comment: It will stop along with your application

Comment: do these jobs run inside spring container/tomcat container or it runs as a Linux cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how you have implemented the scheduler, its not dependent on the tomcat, if you are deploying your spring app in the tomcat and if you stop it it will stop the schedulers too.

Comment: These schedulers are run throw spring configuration by creating beans and passing there reference to the <scheduled/> element in configurations.

Comment: See if you are running your spring container in tomcat container then stopping the tomcat it will stop everything. If you are running the scheduler as a jar application, then irrespective of tomcat it will work. and it has nothing to do with Linux cron jobs. If you are configuring a cron job from crontab then no need of schedulers.